# Body background is having image 1374x1074 but on zooming --, white background is coming

Tags: html, wordpress, css

Here http://singh.mobi/nonni/, I have body background as the image of 1374x1074 but when we zoom in, white background coming to the right side.

Comment: But that's expected on a display with more than 1374 pixels width, no?

Comment: Side note: you can achieve the same effect with CSS gradients I think. That would be easier on the traffic

Comment: can you send me the gradient code for that

Comment: Not really, I would have to look it up myself and I'm off to bed now. I think there are CSS gradient generators, check for them on Google

Comment: The "[Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)" is pretty nifty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days, I would just add `background-size` to the CSS, as that's pretty well supported now:

```
body {
    background: url("images/background.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 #FFF;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: If you're worried about browser compatibility, you may want to provide a fall-back for older browsers. View "background-size" compatibility here: http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

Comment: So essentially it works in everything except IE8. Meh, that seems prety good coverage to me. IE8 has about a 6% user base now anyway, and falling quickly.